# How to script Users or Groups into a folder's Share

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, file-permissions, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I have a bunch of servers with a Shared folder and numerous AD groups that need to have Full Control access to the Share--I don't care right now about the Security tab on that folder--I'm talking about the Sharing/Advanced Sharing tab that I'm currently filling out manually.

I would like to know how to automatically script permissions for the Share itself. All my searching brings me to scripts to set the ACL for the Security, so I'm wondering if someone here can help with scripting the Share permissions. Thanks,

Comment: You should read up on best practices for sharing and NTFS permission. Permissions are always set up on NTFS, and the ACL is the right way to handle this in scripts. Sharing permissions are not where you set security besides the basic can/cannot access. Think of sharing as the door, and NTFS permissions as the guard at that door.

Comment: Yes, I understand that--I want to "open the door" for a set group of people.  Perhaps I shouldn't have said "Full Control", as I can set that with ACL in the Security tab--All I'm looking for is a way to put 20 AD groups in the Share tab without typing each one in that painfully small and useless dialog box.

Comment: Have you looked at the new-smbshare cmdlet?